# How to create excel file witout installing MS Excel in vb.net?

Tags: export

I have to export data to excel file,with/without excel installed in pc

Comment: Can it be exported as CVS file?You can convert it to excel file later.

Comment: how to export in cvs file

Comment: i think he means CSV (comma seperated values) :)

Comment: CSV is an option ONLY if he's not considering anything like formulae or charts. If you're willing to switch languages, I recommend the XLWT package for python

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this. [MyXLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/myxls/)

> MyXLS is a .NET 2.0 library that
>   writes and reads native Excel files
>   quickly and easily, including
>   formatting, multiple sheets, and
>   metadata (the items in the
>   File/Prepare/Properties or
>   File/Properties menu in Excel). Its
>   primary use is generation of Excel 
>   files for ASP.NET sites or .NET
>   applications. It writes files
>   compatible with Excelversions 97 and
>   up, and will read files generated by
>   Excel 97-XP/2003 (and 2007 in
>   Compatibility Mode).
>
> The main advantages over using Excel
>   directly via automation is MyXls
>   doesn't require Excel on the server
>   (or client), it is more reliable
>   regarding system resources, and does
>   not require any special licensing.

It's written in c# but you can just download the source, build it, and then use the dll in your vb project.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative: [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex

> This project is the .NET version of POI Java project at "http://poi.apache.org/". POI is an open source project which can help you read/write xls, doc, ppt files. It has a wide application. For example, you can use it to generate a Excel report without Microsoft Office suite installed on your server and more efficient than call Microsoft Excel ActiveX at background; you can also use it to extract text from Office documents to help you implement full-text indexing feature

Answer (score 0):

MYXLS has this "MyXls.SL2.SortedListEnumerator(Of ",how to use this with vb.net for data from export dataset to excel file