# Export to Excel not working if MS Office is not present on machine

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

You might think this can be a possible duplicate to questions like this:
[How to create excel file witout installing MS Excel in vb.net?](https://superuser.com/questions/102060/how-to-create-excel-file-witout-installing-ms-excel-in-vb-net)

However, this is not the case. I've googled a lot and things are more confusing rather than solving my problem.

Scenario:
We have a [Tally ERP solution](http://www.tallysolutions.com) (support for this software is not helping out on this matter) installed on one of our systems, on which we do not intend to install MS Office, due to heavy license cost. **What we simply want to do a weekly export of the data in xls format** or pdf(this one is working like charm), **without installing MS Office suite.**

I've tried everything from installing Excel viewer to VSTO, but nothing solved our problem.

Can you guys please suggest a solution (free license or open source) to this problem?

Comment: Why not create a `csv` file which can be later imported into excel?

Comment: @brettdj is right, just export into .csv or use another open source spreadsheet application's native format (openoffice, libreoffice). This [tutorial](http://www.accountinghead.com/how-to-export-data-from-tally-to-excel-format-in-tally-6-3tally7-2-nd-tally-8-1.html) might be of use.

Comment: You guys are right on your part, however certain functionality is only available through xls file format and not through the csv. Moreover there are text indent and alignment issues when I see some financial reports in csv format rather than in xls file format, CSV option is explored by us in advance. Thanks though for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved long back actually and until today, I didn't realized to share and close this one. Sorry for that.
We ended up using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB drivers.

The code found for the same was I guess picked up from here on SO
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155642/how-to-read-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp-without-using-microsoft-office-interop-exce

Please share further if you guys like.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to export it in html, and reanme the HTML to .xls.
Some clean up may be required, so simply select all cells, and clear formatting. Also some cells have just spaces and blank otherwise, so:
1. select one such cell
2. select everything in it
3. go to find and replace and paste this selected content
4. replace with nothing

BTW LibreOffice is awesome and these days MicroSoft is copying heavily from Linux and OpenSource applications. Tally should have focused on Free / OpenSource wares and not Proprietary ones. Too Bad!